# angularjs button in bootstrap navigation bar

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I really like the current style of the navigation bar in twitter Bootstrap v3.3.6 and I'm wondering how to wrap angularJS buttons inside them?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">                
      <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/"> Jenny Tech </a>
      </div>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

    <!--<button ng-click="Home()">Home</button>-->

    <li><a href="#/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Putting in `<button ng-click="Home()">Home</button>` simply puts a button that is in a different style and size in the upper right part of the nav bar.

Would appreciate some help on this.

Comment: try this  <li><a  ng-click="Home()" > Home</a></li>

Answer (score 0):

try this May be it will help:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="Home()">Home</button>
```

Comment: This is using angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap and is not the same style as the regular html buttons :/

Comment: Changing the css in my bootstrap.css file did the trick

.btn-lg,
.btn-group-lg > .btn {
  color: #777;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 3px;
}